# whos Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Lets assume I have `X=[1;2;3;4]`, `Z=[2,3,4,5;1,2,3,4]`.
Is the proper command for `whos` to check both variables `whos(X Z)` or `whos(X),whos(Z)` or `whos(X*),whos(Z*)`?
Our lecturer didn't quite discuss this bit and I don't have MATLAB installed yet.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument inside [`whos`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) must be a string so try this

```
>> whos('X','Z')
// or simply whos X Z as mentioned by @A.Donda

Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

X         4x1                32  double              
Z         2x4                64  double
```

The `*` after the letter means to get the information of all the variables starting with that particular letter. I don't think you need to do this in this particular case.

Comment: Or more simply, `whos X Z`.